# Fundo com gradiente em CSS funciona na horizontal mas não pra vertical

Tags: html5, css3, background-color

A réplica do codigo:
https://codepen.io/utamo/pen/XoyzWN

ao aplicar no body:

```
background: linear-gradient(to right, #33ccff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);
```

tenho o seguinte resultado [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

mas ao trocar pra

```
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #33ccff 0%, #ff99cc 100%);
```

acaba ficando assim [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Sei que é algo simples mas me falta conhecimento no momento

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Coloca seu html e body com height 100% e background-repeat: no-repeat